# Ansible - Where does the software that performs a playbook task need to be installed?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ansible

I am using Ansible to modify properties of a running Kubernetes cluster. I **do not** have Ansible installed on the cluster, but rather, externally use an Ansible Docker image to run the playbooks that operate on the cluster nodes. I run the container and pass it the necessary arguments to run playbooks that are configured to operate on K8s cluster nodes.

When a playbook task is executed, it is meant to affect some aspect of the specified host(s) (e.g. a cluster node), correct? That seems rather obvious.

My question:

For a given playbook task, does the software that performs the task need to be present (i.e. installed) on the host, or is it being run remotely from the Ansible "node" (the Docker container in this case)? This is not entirely clear to me.

The reason behind this question is that it appears that I need to install (or have previously installed) certain pieces of software *on the K8s cluster node* in order for some playbook tasks to execute.

I don't want to have Ansible (or other "task" software) installed on my cluster nodes. Do I have no choice in the matter? Is there a way around this?

Here is an example task that fails, unless I have previously installed (via a prior task) a specific module:

```
- name: "Get kube-proxy ConfigMap"
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: kube-proxy
    namespace: kube-system
    kubeconfig: "{{ lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG') }}"
  register: kube_proxy_data
```

For this to execute, I need add the tasks below *ahead* of this:

```
- name: "Install pip"
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip"

- name: "Install kubernetes Ansible module"
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name:
      kubernetes
```

Comment: Did you realise that this whole question would have been answered by [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_info_module.html#requirements): _The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module: python >= 3.6; kubernetes >= 12.0.0; PyYAML >= 3.11_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking. Is it (A) does *Ansible itself* need software to be installed on the node? Or is it (B) Does the node need software to be installed for a *particular task* to run?

If (A) then per [Domenico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75223174/1227469), the node will need SSH and the correct Python version.

If (B) then it depends on that task. For example, if the task is to install software via a package manager then obviously the node will need that package manager installed. If the task is to add a user to a Postgres database, then the node will need Postgres installed. Etc. In general, the node will need whatever it would have needed if you were to perform the task manually on that node.

If you're asking something different then please edit the question to clarify. It may also be helpful to give an example of the type of task you are trying to run.

Comment: I *think* I'm asking B. To provide some context, I have a task in the playbook that uses a Python module, named `kubernetes` to get and later modify some configuration on the K8s cluster. It is the usage of this module that is giving me problems. I need to add a prior task to install the module, then it proceeds further. I suppose I can remove the module after the tasks are complete. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JosephGagnon Ask yourself this question:  can you SSH into the node and carry out the task manually (without Ansible)? If you can't, due to some software being missing on that node, then Ansible will also be unable to do so until that software is present.

Comment: Makes sense when I think about it with that info in hand. I wasn't sure how Ansible worked, i.e. whether it could do anything remotely to a host.

Answer (score 0):

From the redhat [website](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works):

> "Since Ansible is agentless, it can still communicate with devices
> without requiring an application or service to be installed on the
> managed node. "

Answer is, then, no. There is no need to install anything on the managed node, apart from a regular ssh-server daemon and [python](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#id7).

Comment: OK, but then why am I seeing what I'm seeing? If I don't run an earlier task that installs a specific module, the playbook fails, indicating that the module is not installed.